# Clone audio from a virtual device into three physical devices that often are disconnected/connected

Tags: windows, audio, bluetooth, combine, audio-output

I have three audio devices I often switch between. One by 3.5mm through the motherboard, one pair of speakers connected through my monitor, and one pair of Bluetooth headphones. I switch between these and disconnect/connect these very often and some applications in Windows does not play nicely when switching default audio device in Windows. I spend a lot of time opening settings in games or software and changing the "Audio Output" setting.

I'd like to be able to have just one audio output device in Windows, that automatically just sends the audio any of my three audio devices that are connected. It must be a solution that works automatically when connecting/disconnecting any audio device.

This way, I wouldn't ever have to change the default audio device in Windows and never have to change output device in software. Is there a solution for Windows 10? Either in-built or by external software.

If you have an idea for a solution, I have two additional concerns regarding audio delay and CPU performance. How much does it increase audio delay? How demanding is it on the CPU?

Comment: It would be ideal if this solution also could work the same way for microphones. I have two microphones I sometimes switch between that I'd like to just ouput to the same virtual input device.

Answer (score 0):

Audio Switcher is a free utility that will allow you switch your default audio devices according to application, automatically based on preset priorities, or with hotkeys.

https://audioswit.ch/er